# Create Django Project template using cookiecutter on Windows

Tags: python, django, git, cookiecutter

I am trying to create cookiecutter project template in windows. As per the instructions on the official site: https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io, I installed cookiecutter using pip.

Next step mentioned on site is to use following command to create project template using cookiecutter.

cookiecutter https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage.git

I also did that on my windows cmd but it's showing error: 'cookiecutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Can somebody suggest me a way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that:

- [pip is properly installed](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation) (see also [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/))
- you have added to your PATH `%PYTHON_HOME%` and `%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts`

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/fb28d689631f2f4012741f6cf599dd52ed720b92/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f323939363230352f313035383237362f63333566353334612d313138352d313165332d386631622d6439343033633836643939662e706e67]

Then, any `pip install` program should be available.